# Electrostatic force between 2 charges when the medium's dielectric constant is continuously changing

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

This question just came to my mind. I don't know if it's valid or not. I'm just curious.

***Question:*** Charge **q1** and charge **q2** is in a medium and it's dielectric constant changes proportional to the distance between the charges. The distance between the charges is **d**. At the very left the dielectric constant is **K1** and at the very right, the dielectric constant is **K2**. Then what will be the force between the 2 charges?

So know that this problem requires integration but I'm not comfortable with integral problems in physics. So can someone please tell me is the question valid. If yes then how can I solve it?

Edit: How can I make a relation between d and k?

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Force between two charges when the dielectric constant of the material varies?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210437/force-between-two-charges-when-the-dielectric-constant-of-the-material-varies)

Comment: Related : [What is the force between two charged objects when the space between them is partially filled by a dielectric medium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144980/what-is-the-force-between-two-charged-objects-when-the-space-between-them-is-par?noredirect=1&lq=1)